# Use the foreign key that a query selects to get data within the same query

Tags: sql

I have this issue with a query I am trying to build. The idea is that I have 3 tables where two have foreign keys. I want to make a query that selects the foreign key from TABLE A and uses the same key to get data from key B.

So it will look like this:

```
SELECT 
    id, foreignKey1 
FROM 
    tableA 
    (SELECT id FROM tableB WHERE ID = foreignKey1);
```

But somehow I am not able to do this or find any good documentation about it.

Comment: Look up how JOIN works.

Comment: This is what the JOINs are for

Comment: Got it. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple [`INNER JOIN`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191472(v=sql.105).aspx):

```
Select      *
From        TableA  A
Inner Join  TableB  B   On  A.ForeignKey1 = B.Id
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a query that selects the foreign key from TABLE A and uses the same key to get data from key B, below should work,

```
SELECT id, foreignKey1 
FROM tableB 
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM tableA);
```

but joins always gives better performance than sub queries, you can use below query,

```
SELECT b.id, b.foreignKey1 
FROM tableB b 
INNER JOIN tableA ON a.id = b.id;
```